# Control optimization for a black box model

Tags: ds.algorithms, optimization

Computer science is not my major, hence my question is two folded :

- how is defined the problem I have (if I can name it, it will be easier for me to look for references) ?
- what kind algorithm would be more suited to solve it ?

Let's take a wheeled remote controlled turtle (the **real turtle**) and a numerical model of it (the **model turtle**).

We first play once with the **real turtle**, record the commands and the resulting trajectory.

The problem is to find the right commands for the **model turtle** in order to fit (as much as possible) with the trajectory obtained previously with the **real turtle**.

With a perfectly representative model, it won't be an issue at all: for similar commands, one would get similar trajectory. But the model turtle will never be perfect, and commands will need to be tweaked.

Extra constraints are :

- **model turtle** can only be initialized (at t=0) and run forward (in time) to the end of the trajectory (no reverse play, snapshot/recall, etc.). Simulation can be run many times though.
- **model turtle** is in fact a complex black box system, with no known equations of it and a bunch of internal states (mostly filters).

Thanks in advance for the leads

Comment: It seems that you need a control loop, although normally control loops are used to make the physical system behave like the model system rather than vice versa

Comment: With a PID feedback we couldn't obtain good results. Mostly because the link between controls and trajectory are difficult to assess (behavior is deterministic but unknown a priori). Hopefully, I can re-play many times the model (use genetic algorithm ? but how to converge fast ?). I could also use a neural network as an input for a PID, but I have little idea on the best inputs and outputs for the NN.